# How is scope defined in Higher Order Components in React?

Tags: reactjs, scope, components, this

A class in JS is still a function. So my understanding would be that when we create Wrapped1 it will have its 'this' tied to App since it lives inside of it but clearly Wrapped1 has its own scope. I can't figure out where I'm wrong.

```
let HigherOrderComp = (Component) => class extends React.Component{
  construstor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    setInterval(()=>{
      this.setState(
        count: this.state.count + 1
      );
    }, 1000)
  }

  render(){
    return <Component {...this.props} {...this.state}>
  }
}

  class Comp1 extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <p>Comp1</p>
          {this.props.count}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

let Wrapped1 = HigherOrderComp(Comp1);

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <Wrapped1/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An instance of `Wrapped1` is created inside `App`, so it has no knowledge of `App`. If you need access to the `App` instance from within `Wrapped1`, you should pass the data you need as props.

Comment: Thanks, so is that general React architecture that the inner components have no knowledge of the enclosing component or it comes from Javascript?